# How do I pass a selected object from a list activity to a details activity

Tags: android

Sorry if this is obvious but I am very new to andriod (just playing around trying to learn something new).

I think this is a fairly common thing to do, but I am having trouble figuring out the best way to do it.

Right now I have 3 activities.  A main activity that will start a second activity that shows a list of objects, and finally a third activity, started from the list activity, where I want to make changes to the selected object. Both the list and details activities host fragments.

Is there some safe place I store the selected object and retrieve it from the details activity/fragment? It seems like the main activity is the only common link, but I am not sure I can count on that activity not having been destroyed.

Do I need to pass it via an Intent? This seems it would work but also seems overly complicated. (I am thinking I have to serialize the object and return it as a result of the activity)

Should I just combine the final 2 list and details activities into one activity, and swap out the fragments?  I think if I do that I can safely store the selected object in the combined activity, is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common and the right way to do it:

You have to create an object (that you will pass) and implement Parcelable interface ([e.g.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html)) for that object and then pass it with your intent `intent.putExtra("identifier", youParcelable)`

Example:

Add an object while starting new Activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
yourActivityClass.class);
intent.putExtra("identifier", youParcelable);
startActivity(intent);
```

Retrieve object from intent in newly opened Activity:

```
Object object = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("identifier");
```

[Source](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/android-sending-object-from-one-activity-to-another-using-parcelable/)

Comment: Ok, this is sort of my option 2, and seems like a nice way to go. Here is a side question.  Can I create a somewhat generic parcelable class that has just 1 field, say innerObject,  and have a constructor that sets the field to whatever I want?

Comment: @nPn ofcourse you can, but the result will be the same. It is just that you will not pass you "innerObject", but the wrapper of that object, whatever you will create

Comment: thanks I think I understand now. I was thinking I could somehow avoid making the class parcelable this way, but after reading about the Parcel class, I see that is not that case (you can only write specific types and other parcelables).  I guess the only issue would be if your class had a field that was not parcelable, but I guess you could probably find a way to decompose it and recreated it on the other side anyway.  BTW say hello to Ender for me if you see him (the name of your city was a planet in the Enders Game series)

Comment: when you pass date between activities in you intent, the object has to be parcelable, if you declare an object A as parcelable and that object A contains object B, which is not parcelable, then you will only send object A to another activity, without object B. The thing is that when declaring an object as Parcelable, you have to override you constructor and specify which fields you are going to write to Parcel and which not. So, the ones that will be in Parcel, would be sent over to another activity, the others would just becomeNULL. Object is being constructed from beginning on the other side